# How to get max value group by another column from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe. I would like to get the rows where the date is max for each **pipeline_name**

Here is the dataframe:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|    | pipeline_name   | runid                                | run_end_dt                       |
|----+-----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------|
|  0 | test_pipeline   | test_pipeline_run_101                | 2021-03-10 20:01:26.704265+00:00 |
|  1 | test_pipeline   | test_pipeline_run_102                | 2021-03-13 20:08:31.929038+00:00 |
|  2 | test_pipeline2  | test_pipeline2_run_101               | 2021-03-10 20:13:53.083525+00:00 |
|  3 | test_pipeline2  | test_pipeline2_run_102               | 2021-03-12 20:14:51.757058+00:00 |
|  4 | test_pipeline2  | test_pipeline2_run_103               | 2021-03-13 20:17:00.285573+00:00 |
```

Here is the result I want to achieve:

```
+----+-----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|    | pipeline_name   | runid                                | run_end_dt                       |
|----+-----------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------|
|  0 | test_pipeline   | test_pipeline_run_102                | 2021-03-13 20:08:31.929038+00:00 |
|  1 | test_pipeline2  | test_pipeline2_run_103               | 2021-03-13 20:17:00.285573+00:00 |
```

In the expected result, we have only the **runid** against each **pipeline_name** with the max **run_end_dt**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your `dataframe` stored in a variable named `df`

Just use `groupby()` method:-

```
df.groupby('pipeline_name',as_index=False)[['runid','run_end_dt']].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby followed by a transform. Get the indices of the rows which have the max value in each group.

```
idx = (df.groupby(['pipeline_name'], sort=False)['run_end_dt'].transform('max') == df['run_end_dt'])
df = df.loc[idx]
```